# How to find all different lists and place them in another list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a .csv file with 1500 lines and each line looks like this:

```
CS105,A-,ENG101,A-,MATH101,A,GER,B,ENG102,B,CS230,B,MATH120,B,GER,A-,CS205,A,FREE,A-,GER,A-,CS106,B,CS215,B+,CS107,A,ENG204,A-,GER,A-,MATH220,B+,CS300,B,CS206,A,CS306,B+,GER,A-,FREE,B+,CS312,A,CS450,B,GER,B,CS321,B,FREE,A,CS325,A-,GER,B+,CS322,B+,MAJOR,A-,CS310,B,STAT205,A-,A-,CS443,B+,CS412,A,CS421,B+,GER,A-,CS444,B+,FREE,A-,FREE,B,A,B,A-
```

and next line like this:

```
CS105,A-,ENG101,A,MATH101,B,GER,A,ENG102,A-,CS230,B+,MATH120,A-,GER,B,CS205,B+,GER,B+,A,CS106,A-,CS107,B+,CS215,A-,ENG204,A,GER,B,MATH220,A-,CS206,A-,FREE,A-,CS300,B,GER,B+,A,CS312,A,CS450,A-,GER,B,CS321,A,FREE,A-,CS325,B+,CS306,B,CS310,B+,MAJOR,A,GER,A,STAT205,B,B,CS443,A,CS322,B,GER,A,FREE,B,CS444,A,CS412,A,CS421,B+,FREE,A,FREE,B,A-
```

and it goes on. The **CS105** indicates a course, while **A-** indicates the grade that the student obtained in that specific class. What I did is to seperate the courses from the grades and I did this

```
courses = []
grades = []

def DatabaseToList():

    with open('grades.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        mylist = list(reader)
        # print(mylist)

        path = mylist[0:]
        for lists in path:
            for onelist in lists:
                course = lists[::2]
                grade = lists[1::2]
                courses.append(course)
                grades.append(grade)
```

That way I get this result(I am just showing the courses[0] and grades[0]):

```
['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER', 'ENG102', 'CS230', 'MATH120', 'GER', 'CS205', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS106', 'CS215', 'CS107', 'ENG204', 'GER', 'MATH220', 'CS300', 'CS206', 'CS306', 'GER', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS450', 'GER', 'CS321', 'FREE', 'CS325', 'GER', 'CS322', 'MAJOR', 'CS310', 'STAT205', '', 'CS443', 'CS412', 'CS421', 'GER', 'CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE']
['A-', 'A-', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A-', 'A', 'A-', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'A', 'A-', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'A', 'B+', 'A-', 'B+', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B+', 'A-', 'B', 'A-', '', 'B+', 'A', 'B+', 'A-', 'B+', 'A-', 'B']
```

What I want to do is **find all the possible combinations of courses that there are in the courses array** in order to find the average GPA of people that took the exact same courses in the exact same sequence(from the grades array). To be more precise, I want to **find all the combinations that exist and put them only once in a seperate list** so afterwards I can **compare each list with all lists from the array** in order to collect the grades of the same ones and find what GPA each student had and then find the average one.  I searched for how to find unique lists and duplicate lists but it takes a great amount of time to run and show results and it is not what I actually ask for. The code I used is the following:

```
unique_list = []
duplicate_list = []
for i in courses:
    final_list = [unique_list.append(item) if item not in unique_list else duplicate_list.append(item) for item in
                          courses]
```

In other words, in order to make it maybe easier to understand, if there is an array of courses that has:

```
courses = [[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,C,B],[B,C,A],[B,A,C],[B,A,C]]
```

then i want a new list that will contain the following

```
 allUnique = [[A,B,C],[A,C,B],[B,C,A],[B,A,C]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution is to use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

courses = [[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,C,B],[B,C,A],[B,A,C],[B,A,C]]
courses.sort()
allUnique = list(course for course, _ in itertools.groupby(courses))
print(allUnique)  # [[A,B,C],[A,C,B],[B,C,A],[B,A,C]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To take a list,

```
a = [[A,B], [A,B], [B,C]]
```

into

```
[[A,B], [B,C]]
```

you can do

```
list(set(map(tuple,a)))
```

Since you can't use set on 2d arrays, you first convert it into a tuple, then perform the set function on that, and finally convert it back into a list.

Hope that helps!